# How to join queries with Select, Count, and Sum in 1 query

Tags: sql-server

**Is there a way to join all the queries below as One?**

```
SELECT studentNum, (lastName + ', ' + firstName) AS Name, course, year, gender, address FROM tblStudent
```

The second query with count and sum:

```
SELECT
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblBorrowedBook WHERE studentID= @studentID) AS BorrowHistory,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblBorrowedBook WHERE status IN ('Not Returned', 'Overdue') AND studentID = @studentID) AS BooksOnHand,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblBorrowedBook WHERE status = 'Overdue' AND studentID= @studentID) AS BooksOverdue,
(SELECT SUM(CAST([totalFine] AS INT)) FROM tblBorrowedBook WHERE studentID = @studentID) AS PendingFine,
(SELECT SUM(totalPayment) FROM tblPayment WHERE studentID =  @studentID) AS ClearedPayments
```

I would like to make a datatable out of it so I can show it in crystal report.

Comment: can you please provide some sample data and expected output?

Comment: Why use two diff columns?? WHERE studentNum =xx and WHERE studentID = zzz.  And why two diff numbers?  Is that meaningful? or just lazy?  If it is a typo, please correct the above example sql.   Is the report going to show just one student? or ALL students, one at a time?

Comment: @donPablo I actually going to use a parameters for every condition

Comment: @donPablo I have edited the codes

Comment: The first sql returns all students, whereas the second sql has a parameter to return just one student.  Please make them agree.  Also, add a sample sql that does a JOIN, say a Left Join, with its associated ON...

Answer (score 0):

use tsql windows

```
 SELECT  
    distinct
  count(*) over(partition by studentID) BorrowHistory,
  sum(case when status in('Not Return','Overdue') then 1 else 0 end)) over(partition by studentID) BooksOnHand,
  sum(case when status in('Overdue') then 1 else 0 end)) over(partition by studentID) BooksOverdue
  sum(totalFine) over(partition by studentID) PendingFine
  sum(totalPayment) over(partition by studentID) TotalPayment
  ,studentID
  FROM tblBorrowedBook
```

Answer (score -1):

To accomplish this in one SELECT statement you should consider using tsql windowed functions with the appropriate "OVER(PARTITION BY" clauses for your COUNT's and SUM's.

Read this Microsoft Docs for guidance: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15